# what is benefit of creating two object using new operator in string

Tags: java, string

what is benefit of creating two object using new operator in string. Why two objects are created and what is their importance .

```
String s=new String("abc");

//creates two object 

//why 2 object creation is required.
```

Comment: There's very little benefit, and hardly ever required.

Comment: many tools will mark it as a minor bug and will suggest to use `String s="abc"` instead. P.S. why so sure it will create two objects?

Comment: @T.G: normally it should guarantee that if you use the constructor, a new object is created. `string.valueOf` may indeed use a "flyweight" pattern...

Answer (score 1):

If you perform the following test:

```
String a = "foo";
String b = new String(a);
System.out.println(a == b);//returns false
```

So it means `a` and `b` are **not the same object** (this is probably mandatory because the `new` operator is used).

This can be useful if you would use the `==` to check if you are talking about the **same** string (thus not an **equivalent** string).

There is in this case however little use to do so, especially because `String` objects are immutable, as you can read in the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28java.lang.String%29):

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument string. **Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since `Strings` are immutable.**

The only situation where it can be useful I think, if you would attach some kind of "message" aspect to the `String`, where a messageboard only accepts *different object Strings*. If you in that case want to insert the same message twice, you will need to make a copy of the `String`.